# Nunit 3 console runner issue in fixture and xml output generation

Tags: nunit, fixture

I am using final builder 7 actions Nunit with fixture and xml output options.
when i was running with NUnit version 2.6.4 it works fine.
But i have upgraded version to 3.0 ie nunit3.console

Please check this link for final builder options provided for referernce.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdYpG.png

I am facing below issues:

1. Invalid argument /xml
2. Invalid argument /fixture

I have tried to execute like a command as below:

```
nunit3.console.exe Test.dll --fixture=example --xml=example.xml
```

But it didn't work for me.
Did i miss anything in command line syntax?
My goal is to get separate xml files for each class i specified.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Neither `/fixture` nor `/xml` are options of the nunit3-console runner, which is a completely new program. You can check the options by typing `nunit3-console /?` or by reading the docs at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line. It may even be useful to do this before posting questions.

Specifics...

- `/fixture` limited what tests were **loaded** by NUnit to a single fixture. While there is no longer an equivalent option, `/test` limits what tests are **executed** and that's what most people care about. The `/test` option has the advantage that it can be used multiple times on the command-line.
- `/xml` was replaced by `/result`, which can be used the same way or with additional options that are explained in the docs.